# Data can't be loaded on Input flow [close]

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

Using MarkLogic DHF 4.X, trying to load data into staging DataBase.

However, it seems input file path and input file can't be read properly and nothing has been loaded.

I Changed file path and where the file was but still didn't work.

Here's error log.

> 2019-06-27 09:40:57.340 ERROR 2940 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].
> [dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in >context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested >exception is com.marklogic.client.ResourceNotFoundException: Local message: >Could not read resource at resources/ml:flow. Server Message: The requested >flow was not found] with root cause
>
> com.marklogic.client.ResourceNotFoundException: Local message: Could not read >resource at resources/ml:flow. Server Message: The requested flow was not found

I'll be appericiated if you help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. once uninstall project and then re-install, after that, data was loaded.Thanks!